# Какие версии Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable должны быть установлены?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Откуда берется столько программ C++?

Какие из них можно удалить?

При установке какой программы они устанавливаются?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Redistributable C++ (в двух словах - общие библиотеки C++) обычно устанавливаются с программами, которые их используют. Это могут быть какие угодно программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалять ничего ни в коем случае нельзя! **Microsoft Visual C++** нужен для работы **установленных** вами программ, соответственно, если удалите — будут неприятности и различные ошибки.

Кстати, при установке различных игр также устанавливаются и эти **Microsoft Visual C++**, помимо **DirectX**.